# How to move msg.payload from inject node to template node in node red dashboard?

Tags: javascript, node-red

This is template node of node-red dasboard nodes, I need to inject date and time formatted like  "Feb 09, 2018 13:50:05" for example. If I will uncomment first indate var it will work.

```
<script>
// Set the date we're counting down to
//var countDownDate = new Date({{msg.payload}}).getTime();
//var indate = "Feb 09, 2018 13:50:05";
var indate = msg.payload;
var countDownDate = new Date(indate).getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

    // Get todays date and time
    var now = new Date().getTime();

    // Find the distance between now an the count down date
    var distance = countDownDate - now;

    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
    + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

    // If the count down is over, write some text 
    if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
    }
}, 1000);
</script>
```

in my node-red config ui those 2 nodes looks like

```
[{"id":"a600589b.f2b9f8","type":"ui_template","z":"54549b95.190a94","group":"ed0a0688.55eb78","name":"","order":0,"width":0,"height":0,"format":"<div id=\"demo\"></div>\n\n<script>\n// Set the date we're counting down to\n//var countDownDate = new Date({{msg.payload}}).getTime();\nvar indate = msg.payload;\nvar countDownDate = new Date(indate).getTime();\n\n// Update the count down every 1 second\nvar x = setInterval(function() {\n\n    // Get todays date and time\n    var now = new Date().getTime();\n    \n    // Find the distance between now an the count down date\n    var distance = countDownDate - now;\n    \n    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds\n    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));\n    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));\n    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));\n    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);\n    \n    // Output the result in an element with id=\"demo\"\n    document.getElementById(\"demo\").innerHTML = days + \"d \" + hours + \"h \"\n    + minutes + \"m \" + seconds + \"s \";\n    \n    // If the count down is over, write some text \n    if (distance < 0) {\n        clearInterval(x);\n        document.getElementById(\"demo\").innerHTML = \"EXPIRED\";\n    }\n}, 1000);\n</script>\n","storeOutMessages":true,"fwdInMessages":false,"templateScope":"local","x":616.0195846557617,"y":2164.0041790008545,"wires":[[]]},{"id":"fbc5518f.f9f45","type":"inject","z":"54549b95.190a94","name":"","topic":"","payload":"Feb 09, 2018 13:50:05","payloadType":"str","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"x":401.14630126953125,"y":2305.575101852417,"wires":[["a600589b.f2b9f8"]]},{"id":"ed0a0688.55eb78","type":"ui_group","z":"","name":"Время комната 15","tab":"ab7910af.baccb","order":2,"disp":true,"width":"6"},{"id":"ab7910af.baccb","type":"ui_tab","z":"","name":"Клиенты","icon":"dashboard","order":1}]
```

Comment: I'd try to improve this question, but without knowing what `node-red` is it's impossible to know what's going on here.

Comment: https://nodered.org/

Comment: The `msg.payload` object is only available inside the angular scope, not the html <script> element. Use a named function wrapper in place of the setTimeout, and then you can call that function from inside `scope.$watch()` as shown in the `ui_template` info example.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use node-red-contrib-moment before your Dashboard Template node? Use that to attach the correctly formatted date to the msg and then consume within the Dashboard.